# problema de envió de datos de un modal con php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Estoy tratando de enviar una variable de cantidad por medio de un input desde un modal pero no lo envía a la lista, los otros datos si los agrega pero el de cantidad no, y no sé cómo enviarlo. Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

[image: imagen]

Esta es la parte que lista el modal de donde quisiera enviar el dato:

```
case "lista_Dproducto":
     $datos=$Dproducto->get_DproductoB();
   $data= Array();
     foreach($datos as $row)
      {
        $sub_array = array();
        $est = '';        
         $atrib = "btn btn-danger btn-md estado";
        if($row["estado"] == 1){
          $est = 'ACTIVO';
          $atrib = "btn btn-success btn-md estado";
        }
        else{
          if($row["estado"] == 0){
            $est = 'INACTIVO';            
          } 
        }          
         $sub_array[] = $row["numero_Dproducto"];
         $sub_array[] = $row["productoc"];
         $sub_array[] = '<input type="number" name="Nbatida" id="Nbatida" class="form-control"  />';
                 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" onClick="cambiarEstado('.$row["id_Dproducto"].',\''.$row["numero_Dproducto"].'\','.$row["estado"].');" name="estado" id="'.$row["id_Dproducto"].'" class="'.$atrib.'">'.$est.'</button>';
                 $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="" id="'.$row["numero_Dproducto"].'" class="btn btn-primary btn-md "onClick="agregarDetalleB('.$row["id_Dproducto"].',\''.$row["materiales"].'\','.$row["estado"].')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Agregar</button>';                
        $data[] = $sub_array;
      }
      $results = array(
      "sEcho"=>1,
      "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
      "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
      "aaData"=>$data);
    echo json_encode($results);
```

Y esta es la parte en que lista por json, la cual se activa por el botón agregar:

```
let detalles = []
function agregarDetalleB(id_Dproducto,materiales,estado) {
    detalles = [];
    $.ajax({
        url:"../ajax/Dproducto.php?op=buscar_DproductoB",
        type:"POST",
        data:{id_Dproducto:id_Dproducto,materiales:materiales,estado:estado},
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,         
        success:function(data){         
            console.log(data);  
            if(data.error != '') {
                alert(data.error);
            } else {              
                detalles = data.datos;               
                listarDetallesB();
            }
            $('#modalDproducto').modal("hide");
        }  
    });  
}
```

Esta parte es donde extrae los datos desde la base:

```
case "buscar_DproductoB";
    $data = ['error' => '', 'datos' => []];   
    $data['datos'] = $Dproducto->get_DproductoP($_POST["id_Dproducto"], $_POST["estado"]); 
    if(!is_array($data['datos']) || count($data['datos']) == 0) {
        $data["error"] = 'La formula está inactiva, intenta con otro';
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Esta es la parte de el html en que se lista la parte de el modal que envía los datos:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDproducto">
          <div class="modal-dialog ">       
            <div class="bg-warning">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Listado de Formulas</h4>
              </div>             
              <div class="modal-body">
                 <div class="container box">        
        <div class="">   
        <div class="table-responsive">           
             <table id="lista_Dproducto_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">               
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th class="not-mobile desktop tablet-p tablet-l" width="10%">Numero de Formula</th>
                   <th class="not-mobile desktop tablet-p tablet-l" width="10%">Producto</th>
                   <th class="not-mobile desktop tablet-p tablet-l" width="10%">Cantidad</th>                
                     <th class="not-mobile desktop tablet-p tablet-l" width="10%">Estado</th>
                    <th class="not-mobile desktop tablet-p tablet-l" width="10%">Accion</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>          
              </table>
             <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cerrar</button>              
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>   
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>      
        </div>
```

Esta es la parte donde el modal manda datos a listar y donde quiera que el valor que se agrega pueda enviar también a esta lista:

```
function listarDetallesB() {
    $('#listMpriBatida').html('');
    var filas = "";
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var subtotalFinal = 0;
    var totalFinal = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < detalles.length; i++) {
        if(typeof detalles[i].Nbatida == 'undefined' || !detalles[i].Nbatida) {          
            detalles[i].Nbatida = 1;
        }
        if( detalles[i].estado == 1 ) {
            var importe = detalles[i].importe = detalles[i].Nbatida * detalles[i].cantidad * detalles[i].precio;        
            importe = detalles[i].importe;    
            var filas = filas + "<tr><td>"+(i+1)+
            "</td> <td><input type='number'  class='Nbatida input-group-sm' name='Nbatida[]' id='Nbatida[]' onClick='setNbatida(event, this, "+
            (i)+");' onKeyUp='setNbatida(event, this, "+(i)+");' value='"+detalles[i].Nbatida+
            "'></td><td name='materiales[]'>"+detalles[i].materiales+"</td><td name='unidadm[]'>"+
            detalles[i].unidadm+"</td> <td name='precio[]' id='precio[]'>"+
            detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].precio+"</td> <td> <span name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad"+i+
            "'> "+detalles[i].cantidad+"</span> </td> <td> <span name='importe[]' id='importe"+i+
            "'>"+detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].importe+
            "</span> </td><td>  <button href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' role='button' onClick='eliminarBa(event, "+
            (i)+");' aria-pressed='true'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> </button></td> </tr>";
            subtotal = subtotal + importe;
            subtotalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+subtotal;
            var su = subtotal;
            var or=parseFloat(su);
            var total= Math.round(or+subtotal);
            totalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+total;
        }
    }
    $('#listMpriBatida').html(filas);
    $('#subtotal').html(subtotalFinal);
    $('#subtotal_Batida').html(subtotalFinal);
    $('#total').html(totalFinal);
    $('#total_Batida').html(totalFinal);
}
```

Comment: tienes dos errores de semántica el atributo `name` solo se utiliza en unas limitadas etiquetas [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_name.asp) y `let detalles = []` debería ser `var detalles = []` porque let tiene alcance en el bloque y no es de ámbito global

Comment: gracias por la corrección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deberías revisar que la consulta que estas haciendo en la Base de datos devuelva la respuesta con los nombres de columnas que pones acá

```
var filas = filas + "<tr><td>"+(i+1)+
            "</td> <td><input type='number'  class='Nbatida input-group-sm' name='Nbatida[]' id='Nbatida[]' onClick='setNbatida(event, this, "+
            (i)+");' onKeyUp='setNbatida(event, this, "+(i)+");' value='"+detalles[i].Nbatida+
            "'></td><td name='materiales[]'>"+detalles[i].materiales+"</td><td name='unidadm[]'>"+
            detalles[i].unidadm+"</td> <td name='precio[]' id='precio[]'>"+
            detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].precio+"</td> <td> <span name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad"+i+
            "'> "+detalles[i].cantidad+"</span> </td> <td> <span name='importe[]' id='importe"+i+
            "'>"+detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].importe+
            "</span> </td><td>  <button href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' role='button' onClick='eliminarBa(event, "+
            (i)+");' aria-pressed='true'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> </button></td> </tr>";
            subtotal = subtotal + importe;
```

que realmente estas nombrando este índice `detalles[i].cantidad`(cantidad) en tu consulta

**obtener valor Nbatida**

puedes darle un id único al input que luego llamaras en la funcion `listarDetallesB()` asi:

```
$sub_array[] = '<input type="number" name="Nbatida" id="Nbatida'.$_POST["id_Dproducto"].'" class="form-control"  />';
```

y en la funcion

```
for(var i = 0; i < detalles.length; i++) {
    detalles[i].Nbatida = document.getElementById('Nbatida'+detalles[i].idproducto).value;
    if(typeof detalles[i].Nbatida == 'undefined' || !detalles[i].Nbatida) {          
        detalles[i].Nbatida = 1;
    }
```

o puedes declarar una variable global que luego la asignes a `detalles[i].Nbatida`

```
$sub_array[] = '<input type="number" name="Nbatida" id="Nbatida" onchange="javascript: GNbatida=this.value" class="form-control"  />';
```

y en la funcion

```
for(var i = 0; i < detalles.length; i++) {
    detalles[i].Nbatida = GNbatida;
    if(typeof detalles[i].Nbatida == 'undefined' || !detalles[i].Nbatida) {          
        detalles[i].Nbatida = 1;
    }
```

Comment: hola gracias amigo. si todas las consultas que hago ala base de datos la agrega a esa parte, pero el dato de Nbatidas estoy tratando de enviarlo desde un input que se encuentra en el modal, y quisiera que ala agregar ese dato se liste en esa parte tambien, ya que por el momento ese valor esta en1

Comment: ok ya lo edite @wilbertpalacios

Comment: si amigo de la segunda manera funciono

Comment: muchas gracias amigo eres un genio

Comment: @wilbertpalacios la segunda forma la borre porque como estas recorriendo un array se copiaría en todos lo mejor es por la primera

Comment: si todos toman ese valor pero eso era lo que necesitaba, que ese valor multiplicara a todos

Comment: @wilbertpalacios ten en cuenta Gnbatida se sobrescribe cada vez que cambie cualquier input con `onchange="javascript: Gnbatida=this.value"`

Comment: ok con cada evento el cambiara